# How to handle large number of api requests in laravel to reduce the cpu utilization?

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-9

We are using the mobile app to save the coordinates of users when they are driving. location get stored after every 100 meters. when there are multiple users and they are driving at high speed they sent a lot of requests on the server which uses 100% of the CPU. every request use 6Mb of memory.
[image]

I tried to apply the throttle limit of API routes but still, it uses that memory.

There is nothing much in controller function just a db query

```
 public function savePosition(Request $request)
    {
        
        DB::beginTransaction();
        Position::updateOrCreate(['staff_id' => $request->staff_id, 'date' => date('Y-m-d'), 'longitude' => $request->longitude, 'latitude' => $request->latitude],['sort'=>$request->sort,'staff_id' => $request->staff_id, 'date' => date('Y-m-d'), 'longitude' => $request->longitude, 'latitude' => $request->latitude]);
        DB::commit();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Posición guardada correctamente']);
    }
```

I am using AWS ec2 instance for hosting

Comment: Move this in microservice, put data in redis, than read redis from laravel to bulk update database

Comment: microservice means?

Comment: After a  certain volume in requests people usually opt to scale up e.g add more instances of you app and a load balancer. If this is the only demanding part of your application you can re-implement it in something else e.g. as a AWS Lambda function which Amazon autoscales for you. If you don't want to change too much in your app and assuming you have a [queue worker](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues) running you can also rewrite the DB save part as a queued job and add them to the queue as they come and process them in turn

Comment: @webpakistan a small app without laravel which just recive data and put it into storage. You dont need whole framework for this.

Comment: @Maksim do i need to create new instance for that?

Comment: I think @apokryfos is right if you don’t want to change so many things. But also little service for that would be nice or if your application keeps growing you probably need to think about your architectural model, and choose more optimized version. I recommend you to search how big companies does same Uber or there are tons of companies who track location data same way, and try to make the best architectural model for your needs.