# AWS ec2 instance stops at High Usage

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, datastore

We have a Laravel web app hosted on AWS ec2 instance. Normally the cpu utilization is at 10 to 20%. We recieve some network request to store request in order to store coordinates to track user. Controller method is as below

```
DB::beginTransaction();
Position::updateOrCreate(['staff_id' => $request->staff_id, 'date' => date('Y-m-d'), 'longitude' => $request->longitude, 'latitude' => $request->latitude],['sort'=>$request->sort,'staff_id' => $request->staff_id, 'date' => date('Y-m-d'), 'longitude' => $request->longitude, 'latitude' => $request->latitude]);
DB::commit();
return response()->json(['message' => 'Success']);
```

And this method always takes 6MB of memory as we see in **telescope**.

Secondly, We need to store coordiates in local storage on mobile app. so if user does not have internet connection we can track which route did the user took to complete delivery. Sometimes for longer routes the stores coordinates become in count 10k. Now all those 10k rqeuest are getting sent to server every single second. Which causes server to stop every few minutes.

So I have two questions

**1. What is causing 6MB of memory usage in method mentioned above?**

**2. If there is a way we can keep all the records stored somewhere such that server does not have too many network requests (I'm not sure if I am clear or not but my aim is to store all data but not causing too many network requests)**

Thanks,

Comment: 6MB of memory is entirely normal; that's the various bits and pieces of Laravel being loaded in. I get the same memory usage in an empty, fresh install of Laravel.

Comment: ok thanks. Any guess about second question?

Comment: "Now all those 10k rqeuest are getting sent to server every single second." Why is this? Once you've sent the 10k, you should only need to send the *new* coordinates. Can you do less frequent, batched updates? Could you queue the big updates using Laravel's queue, allowing the server time to process them later on? Could you do a bulk-insert instead of a request for every single data point? There are a lot of things to do here.

Comment: Yes I thought of using queues. But it would not work as the queries are very lite. And main issue here the number of requests coming to server.But right now we cannot change mobile app code immediately. That is why I was wondring if there is something we can do on server side

Comment: Queueing will still help, as the database is likely a bottleneck here (especially with transactions), or using something like DynamoDB that's intented for high-volume inserts. Ultimately, though, the mobile app's gonna need tweaking; it shouldn't be sending 10k requests for 10k data points saved up while offline, it should be sending one big request with an array of data you can bulk-insert in one go.

Comment: Yes we do know we need to fix mobile app. But as I mentioned we cannot change app quickly so to save system from crashing over and over again we need a solution which can be implemented on backend side

Comment: so you are saying if we use queues right now it can lessen CPU utilization, resulting in not crashing system over and over again right?

Comment: It may be part of a solution. You've kinda built yourself into a nasty corner here, though.

Comment: ok let us use queues and try to fix the issue temporarily. Thanks for the help mate!

Comment: In addition to the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753515/how-to-handle-large-number-of-api-requests-in-laravel-to-reduce-the-cpu-utilizat?noredirect=1#comment130242351_73753515), your problem is basically [stream processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_processing). If real-time availability of the data is not necessary what typically happens is the data is transmitted to an event stream and then processed via some kind of pipeline. AWS has [kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/) tha might be used for this